# Install Ubuntu 18.04 (mini.iso) on MacMini 2,1

Tags: mac-mini

I'm (desperately) try to install Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit (mini.iso) but I fail in each and every attempt. This is due to the 32 bit BIOS and 64 bit CPU which seems to confuse the installer. Until now, I only was able to install a 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 but I'd like to "upgrade" to a 64 bit base. I have a Mac Min A1176 and tried following:

1) when booting off "ubuntu-14.04.5-server-amd64+mac.iso" on a CD (hoping to so upgrade to 16.04 and 18.04), I get the message: " This kernel requires a x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU."

2) when using the ISO's from here: https://mattgadient.com/2016/07/11/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/ (or creating a patched one myself with the .c program), same problem.

3) I'm not able to create either a bootable USB - not visible - in the bootmenu so I'm burning quite some CD's here (no RW). I have no longer a MACOSX install to create such bootable USB stick.

Anyone that can help me with a guide or procedure how to get Ubuntu (mini or server) installed on this MacMine?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link for bootable macmini2.1 images:

https://mattgadient.com/2016/07/11/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

And links to understand a bit more:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

Hope these sources helps someone.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read these links:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2287767

https://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/

Following these instructions, I have installed 16.04 on two minies a year ago and it worked great. In a short time, I am planning to upgrade them on 18.04 accordingly...

If I remember correctly I used "regular" 64-bit DVD image to boot and install and installed grub-efi-ia32...

With 18.04 I am planning to do it accordingly.

Cheers!

Comment: I've got issues when installing grub-efi-ia32 , with LUbuntu 18.04 , did it worked for you?

Comment: Hi @user894726

Sorry for the late answer but now I 've some time again, this is what I tried:

I've burned an ISO rEFInd , but when booting up, it only shows a black screen with blanking white cursor and it's stuck (waited for hours).

What where your results of trying to get Ubuntu 18.04 (mini or server) installed?

thanks,
br,Koen